# send data from tooltip to div is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i want to pass the data from tooltip to div.
see this image [image]

i want to pass id when we click on contact advertiser (see in image)

i tried so many codes but no success yet.

tried this javascript code but this is working on other parts of page but when i am trying this on tooltip its not working..
what to do????

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//send clicker data to div
    $(function() {  
        $(".clicker").click(function(){
            var data = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: "db_data=" + data,
                success: function(){
                    //alert(data);
                    $('.div-5-owner').text(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You have named the variable as data, which is also a property name in the ajax call. Try changing the name of variable other than 'data'

Answer (score 0):

Pass `data` in `callback` of `success` like,

```
success:function(data){ // <-- you missed data here which is your server response
            //alert(data);
            $('.div-5-owner').html(data);
}
```

Comment: please elaborate i am new in jquery

Comment: actually ajax is not getting called when i am trying to call from tooltip.but its working when i am trying to call this from page or any other div

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this part

```
success: function(my_text){
                    //alert(my_text);
                    $('.div-5-owner').text(my_text);
                }
```

data is reserved variable

Answer (score 0):

You are using data variable for assigning ID while it's a reserved word for $.ajax().
Change the variable name and try :

```
 $(".clicker").click(function(){
           var id1 = $(this).attr('id');
           console.log(id1);
           console.log("db_data=" + id1);
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: "db_data=" + id1,
                success: function(response){ // Here pass the server response as any variable like I used response
                    //alert(response);
                    $('.div-5-owner').text(response);
                }
            });

        });
 });
```

It should work as you want.